# Ambiguous fread()/fwrite() documentation

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, posix, stdio

After RTFM, it is now somewhat unclear to me what I can really infer from the return value of fread()/fwrite() if the returned value is less than the number of requested elements.

Consider at first

```
nhave = fread(dst, 1, nwant, fp);
```

From the C17 standard ([7.21.8.1/3](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#subsection.7.21.8)):

> The **fread** function returns the number of elements successfully read which may be less than *nwant* if a read error or end-of-file is encountered.

Hence, if nhave < nwant upon return, there *could* have been a read error or eof (but there could be other reasons as well). Since it's *if* and not *only if*, one cannot conclude `feof(fp)` if `!ferror(fp)`in this case. If `!ferror(fp)`, it could still have been a successful read (of nhave bytes) according to the standard.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=msvc-160) and [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread) have the same wording.

But then [POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html):

> Upon successful completion, fread() shall return the number of elements successfully read which is less than *nwant* only if a read error or end-of-file is encountered.

Hence, if nhave < nwant upon return, there *must* have been a read error or eof (there cannot be other reasons). Thus in this case, one can conclude `feof(fp)` if `!ferror(fp)`. While being different from the specification in the C Standard, this behavior is not flagged as an extension to the C Standard in POSIX.

And from the fread(3) manual page on Linux (a POSIX-conforming platform):

> If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

Formally, this is the reverse (!) statement to that from POSIX.

Now consider fwrite(),

```
nhave = fwrite(src, 1, nwant, fp);
```

Let's start with [POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) here:

> The fwrite() function shall return the number of elements successfully written, which may be less than *nwant* if a write error is encountered.

Hence, if nhave < nwant, there *could* (but need not) have been a write error. One cannot conclude `ferror(fp)`in this case but need to check.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fwrite?view=msvc-160) and [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) have the same wording.

However, according to the C17 standard ([7.21.8.2/3](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#subsection.7.21.8)), one can conclude more:

> The **fwrite** function returns the number of elements successfully written, which will be less than *nwant* only if a write error is encountered.

Hence in this case, nhave < nwant does imply a write error and thus `ferror(fp)`.

This is even more bizarre than in the case of fread() above since POSIX, Windows, and C++ are each supposed to follow the C standard.

So, what's going on here? Just sloppy wording? In particular and from a programmer's point of view:

Can I assume the POSIX wording for the return value of fread() (as given above) also for C/C++/Windows/..., i.e., does nhave < nwant imply a read error (and thus, ferror(fp)) or eof (and hence, feof(fp))?

Can I assume the C wording of the return value of fwrite() (as given above) also for C++/Windows/POSIX/..., i.e., does nhave < nwant imply a write error (and thus, ferror(fp))?

Comment: How is it bizarre? C specifies the possible results are in some set S. POSIX says the possible results are in some set T. T is a subset of S. So all results that conform to the POSIX specification also conform to the C specification. Why is there a question about “supposed to follow the C standard”? T conforms. The only discrepancy is that this is not noted as an extension. But I can see people viewing an extension as something that is a notable extra behavior, rather than simple narrowing of the possibilities…

Comment: … For example, requiring `int` to be 32 bits is technically an extension of the C standard, but few people would call it that outside a formal mathematical context.

Comment: Did you observe behavior contrary to what is stated? Or are you simply confused with the wording of the documentation? Please clarify which one and update your post and title with your revised question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Because in case of fwrite() it's just the opposite of what you stated. The behavior specified in the C Standard is more strict than that mandated by POSIX and MSDN.

Comment: _Hence, if nhave < nwant, there could (but need not) have been a write error. One cannot conclude ferror(fp)in this case but need to check._ How are you coming to that conclusion from reading **The fwrite() function shall return the number of elements successfully written, which may be less than nwant if a write error is encountered.**? The documentation clearly states that if the number of bytes written is less than what was intended, then a write error has occurred. I can think of no other way to check for a write error than using `ferror`. This is why I recommend you create a test program.

Comment: @smac89: "If a write error is encountered, then less than nwant bytes may have been written" is obviously not equivalent to "If less than nwant bytes have been written, then a write error is encountered.". In the latter case, ferror(fp) is implicit, in the former not.

Comment: @plexando If you are going to claim they are not the same, then support your claim with some evidence. Produce a program that has written less bytes than intended but `perror` returns 0. Once you do that, you can have grounds to claim the documentation is inconsistent, and perhaps even be able to point to the inconsistency. At this point, your question is only going to attract opinionated answers/theories. As for me, I see no inconsistency

Comment: @smac Evidrnce of actual prgrams when making critcism of standards wording is not a requirement.  The OP admitted a plausible reason is sloppy writing; "only if" and "if" being equivalent *is* sloppy, they have different meanings. What more, this question is tagged "language lawyer": it is aimed at understanding what standards *say* as much as what programs and implementations *do*. If you don't like discussing what standards say, don't comment, read or answer "language lawyer" tagged posts. Complaining they are talking about wording is like complaining a java tagged question talks about java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what's going on here? Just sloppy wording?

I think you are parsing words too finely, which you can characterize as sloppy wording of the specifications if you prefer.

Consider `fread()` first.  C17 says,

> The `fread` function returns the number of elements successfully read,
> which may be less than `nmemb` if a read error or end-of-file is
> encountered.

I grant that that wording does not explicitly state that error or end-of-file are the only reasons for fewer items to be read than were requested, but if that were not the intention then why would error and end-of-file conditions be mentioned at all?

The C17 wording for `fwrite` is unambiguous:

> The `fwrite` function returns the number of elements successfully written, which will be less than nmemb only if a write error is encountered.

Comparing the two, one could follow two different lines of reasoning:

1. That the two functions are meant to be analogous, so the ambiguous wording for `fread` should be interpreted in the same "only if" sense as is explicitly specified for `fwrite`, OR
2. That the same wording would have been used for the two if the same interpretation had been intended.

I find the first more persuasive, especially given that it also explains why the `fread` docs even mention error and end of file conditions.  I am entirely prepared to accept that despite the committee's best intentions, the language of the specification is less than perfect.

Comment: The ultimate goal of fread() is to read a given number of data elements of a given size. Hence, an implementation should only return prematurely on EOF or if an error occurred. This would favor your first interpretation. But then again, still somewhat speculative.